# regular expression in perl in form get

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $formget='(90-?A(SB)?)';

if ($form_type=~/$formget/i)
```

This regular expression gets files that are 90-A and 90-ASB but it also gets 90-A/A and 90-ASB/A.

But I want to get ONLY those that have 90-A and 90-ASB and NOT those with 90-A/A and 90-ASB/A..

What change should I make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is fine. Use anchors to limit where the regex matches

`^90-?A(SB)?$`

**Changes made**

- `^` anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `$` anchors the regex at the end of the string

These anchors ensure that the string always starts with `90` and immediatly ends on encountering an `A` or `ASB`.

`90-A/A` fails because after an `A` , `/` is encountered where as the regex expects a `$`

and

`90-ASB/A.` fails because after an `A` , `S` is encountered where as the regex expects a `$`

Comment: Thanks null pointer, it seems I don't get regular expressions that well yet :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only match beginning `90-` mean my code will be useful for you. If your file data like me. This gets `90-A` and `90-ASB`

```
@da=<DATA>;
@ans=map{m/90-A$|90-ASB$/g} @da;
print "@ans\n";

__DATA__
90-A/A
90-ASB
90-A
90-ASB
90-B
```

Comment: Explanation is more use full for other users. :)